# How to remove/hide the title field from a list

Tags: list, content-type

I am creating custom list and do not want to use the title.
I know I can rename, but I do not want to do that.

Some weeks ago I did do this (but have forgotten!!).  I went to advanced settings, turned on manage content types.  Then I do not remember the next steps....

Answer (score 2):

Go to List -> Advanced settings -> select 'Allow manage content types'

Under Content types in List settings -> Click on 'Item'

In the Item content type you will see the 'Title' column marked as required.

Click on the 'Title' column and select 'Hidden' (Will not appear in Forms)

And you are good to go.

Comment: Just for full disclosure, by hiding the Title column and not renaming it, you lose all of the Edit Control Block and the only way to modify the item is by adding the Edit button to your views.

Comment: Hi  Thanks for that. Just to confirm if I change the item content type setting, will this not affect other lists that I create in the same site?